# How do I display value of this argument in Text using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, arguments

I want to display value of *nic* in my app Text view section ?
my app developed using Flutter.
arguments pass as

```
class SetAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  String nic;
  SetAccount({this.nic});
```

and I want display this *nic* value in my List here

```
 new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
        title: const Text('Your Nic'),
        subtitle: const Text ("nic"),
      ),
```

how can I do that in flutter ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

**Change**

```
subtitle: const Text ("nic")
```

**To**

```
subtitle: const Text ('${widget.nic}')
```

> You can use ${} to interpolate the value of Dart expressions within
> strings. The curly braces can be omitted when evaluating identifiers:

#### References

- [String-class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/String-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

change "nic" to "`widget.nic`"

```
new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.today),
        title: const Text('Your Nic'),
        subtitle: const Text (widget.nic),
      ),
```